# Performance comparison: strstr() vs std::string::find()

Tags: c++, c, string

Can someone please explain why I should use strstr or string find() ? Which one is faster, at where ?

Comment: Depends on the details of the implementation of each, which depends on your toolchain.  Is performance the best reason to choose between them? I would guess not; std::string::find is more idiomatic C++.  If performance is really an issue, benchmark both.

Comment: I would imagine they are both O(n) and "sufficiently well optimized" ..

Comment: Actually `strstr` is often `O(nm)`. There are only two known algorithms for `O(n)` time without unbounded memory usage, and most implementations do not take advantage of either of them...

Comment: @R.. Thanks for the correction. I was thinking of only a single character search ^^

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C++ you should use std::string::find(), in C you should use strstr(). The difference in performance should not be significant.

Comment: According to my benchmarks, as of 25.06.2013: for GCC, string::find is slightly faster (~10%) (x86_64, -march=native, ran on AWS) - for MSVC 2, times slower (x86, SSE2, on AMD desktop). (full optimizations)

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't matter which is faster. Much more important is that the std::string::find is safe. So use std::string class and avoid old c functions, if you are going to use c++.

Comment: There's nothing particularly unsafe about `strstr`. But you're right that C++ should be written as C++, not muddled C.

Comment: @JerryCoffin why there is nothing particularly unsafe about the strstr? If your buffer doesn't contain the null termination character then the strstr will probably iterate over the memory which is out of your buffer, on the other side the std::string::find will guarantee that you are working on your buffer.

Comment: An unterminated string is roughly equivalent to a mangled `std::string`, which can also lead to looking at memory outside the buffer. In either case, munged parameters lead to problems, and correct parameters prevent them.

Comment: @AlexTheo Merrily passing non-sanitized raw data taken as use input to various functions is not safe. Don't do that. It has nothing to do with `strstr` or any other function. The purpose and responsibility of a string search function is _not_ to sanitize user input. It's convenient to blame various library functions for bugs caused by bad programming though... it's always someone else's' fault.

Comment: The origin of all this nonsense thinking is some old Microsoft study where they looked at which functions that were most often involved in bugs and exploits. The conclusions made were premature though. `strstr`/`strcpy` etc were often involved so they have to be blamed, right?

Comment: But that's like making the conclusion that boats and water are often involved in drowning accidents, so to prevent drowning we should forbid boats and water. Looking a bit deeper and applying common sense might reveal the actual reasons though, such as driving under the influence. And the actual fix would be to put an alcolock on the boat so that it doesn't start if you are drunk. Input santiation = no boat crashes due to drunk driving. Now with that in place, those sober can enjoy boats and water just fine. Turns out those weren't to blame for the problem.

Comment: @Lundin I would suggest to check the statistics on where you have the most of the bugs coming from. Especially security issues. Then you will understand why that conclusion!
You can be very careful and even write bugs free code with c strings and so on but your brain would be mostly working on being careful instead of solving the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Most of the bugs of the "exploit" nature comes from poor input sanitation. So indeed the problem is solved by doing some manner of input sanitation. And not mix that up with your actual algorithm using unrelated functions such as  `strstr`, that have nothing to do with taking input what-so-ever.

Answer (score 4):

I've benchmarked several versions of searching substring in string.

GCC 10.3 with std=c++20/-O3 shows the following results:

- strstr is the fastest
- std::string::find ~3 times slower
- std::search ~4.5 times slower
- std::string_view::find ~ 11 times slower

Clang 12:

- strstr is the fastest
- std::string::find ~3 times slower
- std::search ~5.5 times slower
- std::string_view::find ~ 8.5 times slower

So if you do care about performance use strstr.

Comment: Why `string_view::find` is slower than `string::find`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void strstr()
{
 auto const start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
 const char* strsource = "Lorem Ipsum is simplystd::chrono::system_clock::now() dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
 for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    std::strstr(strsource, "Aldus");
 }
 auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
 std::cout << "strstr microsecs: "<< std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count();
}

void find()
{
auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
 const std::string strsource = "Lorem Ipsum is simplystd::chrono::system_clock::now() dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
 for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    (void)strsource.find("Aldus");
 }
 auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
 std::cout << "std::string::find microsecs: "<< std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count();
}

int main() 
{
    strstr();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    find();
    return 0;
}
```

If you run this code in compiler explorer you will see that strstr is way faster than string::find function BUT for this particular case. I think this function is very dedependant of the position and the length of the subtstring you are searching for.

strstr microsecs: 2308

std::string::find microsecs: 13327

gcc 13.2 -O0 -std=c++17

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which was about performance.

Comment: You're right. I edited my post with the asnwer